# How to simulate "table-layout:fixed" in mPDF?

Tags: php, mpdf

I have a table and set the table layout to fixed and used mPDF to convert it to PDF.
But it's not working and width of cell is change by content.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use display:block element for that particular td, and use min-width instead of width.Try to put either percentage or pixels, dont mix up both. Sometimes it may work.